# Background Blur in flutter application

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, blur

im new in flutter,and i need your help in my prject..

So i have two place that i need to show blur in background of my application

**1)When my FloatingActionButton (i use this `flutter_speed_dial`) Menu is open**

**Design in Figma : **

[image]

I dont know how to set blur in the background?

**2)When BottomSheet is open**

**Design in Figma :**

[image]

Acctuly for this one I tryd `BackdropFilter` Like this but It isn't what I need

```
//todo Blur To Background
// this is method for show bottom sheet in all the project
void showChiscoBottomSheet(BuildContext context, Widget child) {
  showModalBottomSheet<void>(
    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(25))),
    barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
    backgroundColor: Styles.backGroundColor,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    enableDrag: true,
    isDismissible: true,
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      //Here BackdropFilter But doesn't work right.....
      return BackdropFilter(
        filter:
            ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 1, sigmaY: 0.1, tileMode: TileMode.clamp),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: AnimatedPadding(
            padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
            child: Padding(
              padding: bottomSheetPaddings,
              child: child,
              //this child is bottom sheet widget
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

**Result :**

[image]

if I add to `sigmay` or `sigmax` in `BackdropFilter` the blur part is covering the bottom sheet part and its not good

please help me if you know how can i fix these problems...

***Thanks***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for bottom sheet -

```
 showModalBottomSheet(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (context) {
                            return BackdropFilter(
                                  filter:ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
                              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 400,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    child: Center(child: 
                                                  Text("hello")),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          });
```

for speed dial -

1. use a variable blurValue with intial value is 0.0
2. wrap your SpeedDial with

   BackdropFilter(
   filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: blurValue, sigmaY: blurValue),
   )
3. Speed dial's on Open and on Close

   onOpen: () {
   debugPrint('OPENING DIAL');
   setState(() {
   blurValue = 5;
   });
   },
   onClose: () {
   debugPrint('DIAL CLOSED');
   setState(() {
   blurValue = 0.0;
   });
   },

Comment: Thanks for your help,,and what for bottom sheets

Comment: showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              builder: (_) {
                return Container();
              }).then((value) {
                //set blur value 5.0 using set state.
              });   
//and when you are using Navigator.pop(context) use set state and set blur value to 0.0

Comment: if I wrap my home page widgets (parent widget) to blur,,,,,,my home componnets (all widgets in home) dosent work...It seems its locked...Do you have any other solution?

Comment: Sorry for the problem. I have updated my answer.